# How to get a list of dictionaries sorted by three criteria

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, sortedlist

I want to get a list sorted accordingly to the following rules `persons.sort(key = lambda p: (abs(p["height"] - 180), p["weight"]==75, p["weight"]))` i.e. I need it to get sorted firstly by its closeness to the height 180, then all of the weight values which are equal to 75, and then I want them to be sorted ascendingly by its weight...

I came up with the following code, which is not working...

```
def get_ordered_list(persons):
    persons.sort(key = lambda p: p["name"] )
    persons.sort(key = lambda p: (abs(p["height"] - 180), p["weight"]==75, p["weight"]))
    return persons
```

For the following sample data, for instance,

```
array = [{"name": "Guido Batista", "height": 195, "weight": 110},
    {"name":"Heitor Tostes", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
    {"name":"Bruno Costa", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
    {"name":"Joao Kleber", "height": 180, "weight": 65},
    {"name":"Rafael Rodrigues", "height": 165, "weight": 110},
    {"name":"Ricardo Neto", "height": 170, "weight": 70},
    {"name":"Juca Carvalho", "height": 180, "weight": 77}]
```

I need to get the list sorted as such:

```
[
      {"name":"Bruno Costa", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
      {"name":"Heitor Tostes", "height": 180 , "weight": 75},
      {"name":"Joao Kleber", "height": 180, "weight": 65},
      {"name":"Juca Carvalho", "height": 180, "weight": 77},
      {"name":"Ricardo Neto", "height": 170, "weight": 70},
      {"name": "Guido Batista", "height": 195, "weight": 110},
      {"name":"Rafael Rodrigues", "height": 165, "weight": 110},
]
```

Comment: Can you please specify what is the error that is occurring.

Comment: Oh, yeah.. I can...
The result is being outputed as such 
[{'name': 'Joao Kleber', 'height': 180, 'weight': 65},
{'name': 'Juca Carvalho', 'height': 180, 'weight': 77},
{'name': 'Bruno Costa', 'height': 180, 'weight': 75},{'name': 'Heitor Tostes', 'height': 180, 'weight': 75}, {'name': 'Ricardo Neto', 'height': 170, 'weight': 70}, {'name': 'Guido Batista', 'height': 195, 'weight': 110}, {'name': 'Rafael Rodrigues', 'height': 165, 'weight': 110}]... Which is not the correct order...  It's actually not leveraging the second criterium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `False` is a lower value than `True`. Use

```py
 persons.sort(key = lambda p: (abs(p["height"] - 180), p["weight"]!=75, p["weight"]))
```

changing the comparison for the "weight" key.

Answer (score 0):

This would give the desired result without complicating further:

```
persons.sort(key = lambda p: (abs(p["height"] - 180), not(p["weight"]==75), p["weight"]))
```

By default the sorting order is ascending. And the last piece of puzzle is this (from [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy))

> Booleans: These represent the truth values False and True. The two
> objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean
> objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of plain integers, and Boolean
> values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all
> contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the
> strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively

In the ascending order 0 comes before 1 and that's why this line posted above would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
array = [
    {"name": "Guido Batista", "height": 195, "weight": 110},
    {"name": "Heitor Tostes", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
    {"name": "Bruno Costa", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
    {"name": "Joao Kleber", "height": 180, "weight": 65},
    {"name": "Rafael Rodrigues", "height": 165, "weight": 110},
    {"name": "Ricardo Neto", "height": 170, "weight": 70},
    {"name": "Juca Carvalho", "height": 180, "weight": 77},
]

array = sorted(
    array,
    key=lambda p: (
        abs(p["height"] - 180),
        p["weight"] != 75,
        p["name"],
        -p["weight"],
    ),
)
print(array)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"name": "Bruno Costa", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
    {"name": "Heitor Tostes", "height": 180, "weight": 75},
    {"name": "Joao Kleber", "height": 180, "weight": 65},
    {"name": "Juca Carvalho", "height": 180, "weight": 77},
    {"name": "Ricardo Neto", "height": 170, "weight": 70},
    {"name": "Guido Batista", "height": 195, "weight": 110},
    {"name": "Rafael Rodrigues", "height": 165, "weight": 110},
]
```